# Internet Explorer 9 Bootstrap 3 wp-less issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm facing a wired issue when I view my site on Internet Explorer 9 many css classes are broken. In other words when I view the source i see that many classes are not appearing and media queries are no there:

```
.container {
    width: 768px;
}
.container {
    width: 1008px;
}
.container {
    width: 1008px;
}
```

Rather than show the code like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    width: 1008px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    width: 1008px;
  }
}
```

What do you thing the cause of this issue?
Do you think that the issue is related to wp-less when compiling bootstrap less files?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the reason is because Bootstrap is not actually supported in IE 9, but there is a fix for it.

Comment: Bootstrap mentions their website: "On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11." So they full support it: [Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support). My problem is related to rendering the css class order in less. @buddhistbeast

Comment: Any updates for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will never see a compiled code like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    width: 1008px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    width: 1008px;
  }
}
```

So it would be better if you share your site url with us so we can check it for you.

Comment: Actually the website is currently developing on local machine. But why I can see it on Google Chrome? I think wp-less is not compiling it normally.

Comment: Yes that could be a issue. Please try to go with normal css and check what happen with that. Thanks

Comment: Be sure before submitting an answer @media always in css file!

Comment: Do not, ever, ask for a site URL. It's easier to troubleshoot an issue with code.